# Сортировка вложенного массива функцией usort

Tags: php, сортировка

Сортирую массив, один из элементов которого - тоже массив, который так же надо отсортировать. Внешний массив сортируется, а внутренний - нет. Интересует сортировка только функцией usort. В чём я ошибся?

```
    <?php

$products = [
  ['meat' => 1, 'price' => 250],
  ['water' => 1, 'price' => 30],
  ['juice' => 1, 'price' => 50],
  ['tea' => 1,  'price' => 75],
  ['group' => 1,  'price' => [
    ['fruits' => 1,  'price' => 90],
    ['vegetables' => 1,  'price' => 75],
    ['cereals' => 1,  'price' => 80]
  ]]
];




usort($products, function($item1, $item2){
  if (!is_array($item1['price']) && !is_array($item2['price'])) {
    return $item2['price'] <=> $item1['price'];
  } elseif (is_array($item1['price'])) {
    usort($item1['price'], function($it1, $it2){
      return $it2['price'] <=> $it1['price'];
    });
  }  elseif (is_array($item2['price'])) {
    usort($item2['price'], function($it1, $it2){
      return $it2['price'] <=> $it1['price'];
    });
  }
});

print_r($products);
```

Comment: так не получится, да и смысла нет, представляете сколько раз вы будете этот внутренний массив сортировать. Отсортируйте внешний, пробежитесь циклом и отсортируйте внутренние

Comment: https://ibb.co/zVsPMVx  и что ты тут собрался сортировать?

Comment: @Bloom, как что? Массив - внешний и внутренний

Comment: @splash58 , значит, usort не подходит для сортировки вложенных массивов?

Comment: пример на картинке покажи что с чем должно поменяться

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov подходит, но не при сортировке внешних

Comment: @Bloom ничего не надо показывать картинками. Тогда уже текстом, Но в данном случае и так понятно - отсортировать по цене нужно

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov Вы скажите, чего вы хотите добиться? Вам какую цену из массива для сортировки элемента нужно брать?

Comment: @splash58, я хочу, чтобы элементы внешнего массива были отсортированы от большего к меньшему - этого я добился, а также, чтобы элементы внутреннего массива были отсортированы таким же образом. Грубо говоря:
[9,6,4,2,[5, 2, 0]];

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov а почему не  `[9,6,[5, 2, 0],4,2]` ?

Comment: Надо определиться, куда девать элементы со структурной ценой. Дальше все просто

Comment: @splash58 , задача отсортировать по отдельности - во внешнем массиве и во внутреннем. То есть внутренний массив никак не зависит от внешнего, а лишь является его элементом.

Comment: у вас в реальных данных будет несколько групп [9,6,[5, 3],4,[7,4], 2] ? куда девать группы относительно обычных элементов, как сравнивать их между собой, каков их порядок? Каков порядок групп?

Comment: @splash58 , в данном случае положение группы неважно. Мне нужно сделать сортировку внутреннего и внешнего массива. В реальных данных - может быть, но сейчас надо именно так, как я описал.

Comment: хорошо, группа - элемент массива, чтоб его отсортировать, вы должны сказать алгоритм сравнения, который для чисел - обычных их порядок. Но мы должны уметь сравнивать **все элементы** между собой. В вашем случае, надо знать, что есть результат сравнения массива  с числом и тоже для двух массивом. Или выбрасывайте группы из массива фильтром и сортируйте, что останется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как у вас неоднородная структура данных, то сортировать одной функцией не получится.
Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```
usort($products, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['price'] <=> $b['price'];

});

foreach ($products as &$value) {

    if (is_array($value['price'])){
       usort($value['price'], function($a, $b) {
        return $a['price'] <=> $b['price'];
       });

    }
}
```

Comment: *Так как у вас неоднородная структура данных,* - а если бы была однородная?

Comment: Тогда логичнее использовать array_multisort, например.

Comment: а как у вас будет вот это работать `$a['price'] <=> $b['price'];` если один из элементов массив?

Comment: Согласно формальному описанию операции "космический корабль"). Один аргумент int, второй array. array больше int.

Comment: так что, оно конечно, ошибок не даст, но выяснить, что надо, я так и не смог

Comment: @becouse , Ваше решение дало нужный результат. Поясните, пож-та, момент - почему в цикле используете &$value (передачу по ссылке)?

Comment: Чтобы изменялся элемент массива.  Иначе сортировка будет, но сам массив не изменится.